# reinterpret_cast and use with CV_MAT_ELEM

Tags: c++, opencv

i want to put all the data of an 8 bit input colorimage (Inputfile is a.bmp file)
in a new 16 bit Mat Array.

I do this because i need to sum up several image patches and then build the meanvalue for each pixel.

```
Mat img = imread(Inputfile);   //there now should be values between 0 and 255
```

Addressing the blue value for example like follows

```
uchar* ptr = img.data + img.step*row;
cout << ptr[n*col] << endl;
```

only brings up single Letters and no values.

```
cout << static_cast<short>(ptr[n*col]) << endl;
```

Typecasting to short or bigger brings up the correct values. but a cast to unsigned char (which is the correct datatype in my opinion) brings up the same Letters than without any typecast.

Short has 2 Bytes as i know, but a color .bmp should only have 1 Byte color information per channel. As i need to sum up in worst case 81 (smaller 128=7bit) pixel values, i thought the short as a target value would be great.

Any help concerning the right way to get simple access to the 8 bit values and use them in 16bit arrays would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: In C (the question is tagged C) use `"%d"` in `printf()`: `printf("%d", 'F');`. Also there's a lot of syntax errors in your snippet.

Comment: Removed "c" tag. Your program is in C++, not in C.

Comment: ty n.m. that was left over from another question i wanted to asked. simply forgot to remove it.

pmg, the syntax error you mention is present in c++ as well ?

Answer (score 1):

The cast works correct, but if you send an unsigned char into the output stream, it will be interpreted as a character and printed as a character.

Also note that OpenCV already has functionality to convert a matrix to a different datatype. You can even read your image into a matrix of the preferred datatype:

```
cv::Mat3s img = cv::imread(...);
```

And **it is disregarded to use the data pointer**. Read OpenCV documentation on how to access single pixels or rows in a clean fashion (iterators, operator(), operator[]...).

Comment: +1.  cout recognising a char and presenting it as such doesn't affect the integer assignment when doing short = char.

Comment: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/fast_element_access.html
I use the first method now and thatway i hand over my values into another Matrix with type ushort.

Is there a reason for it beeing disregarded?

anyway thx for the hint to try it another way ;)

Comment: Well, the main reason is that it is more error-prone. Also it is easier to read your code if you use the new methods that better encapsulate the mechanics inside the Mat object. Note that the data pointer is public only for historical reasons (for easier porting of old code). It is not deprecated, so if you have existing code there is no urge to rewrite it.